# How can I shift column values and add new ones in a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have to create a new column in my CSV data with PowerShell.

There is my code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$NewCSVObject = @()  
foreach ($item in $csv)  
{  
    $NewCSVObject += $item | Add-Member -name "ref" -value " " -MemberType NoteProperty  
}  
$NewCSVObject | export-csv -Path ".\test2.csv" -NoType

$csv | Export-CSV   -Path ".\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Append
```

When I open the file, the column is here but a the right and I would like to have this at the left like column A. And I don't know if I can export the two object in one line like this (it doesn't work):

```
$csv,$NewCSVObject | Export-CSV   -Path ".\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Append
```

The input file (It would have more lines than just the one):

```
A      B      C      D       E     F    G     H
T-89  T-75   T-22    Y-23   Y-7   Y-71
```

The current output file:

```
A      B      C      D       E     F    G     H
Y-23   Y-7   Y-71   ref:    ref2:
```

The expected result in the Excel table, display "ref:" and "ref:2" before the product columns:

```
A      B      C      D       E     F    G     H
ref:  T-89   T-75   T-22   ref2:   Y-23  Y-7  Y-71
```

Comment: All of this is just to add a column at the beginning correct? I can explain this but I want to be sure what you are trying to do. Some sample input data would be helpful. I see you are adding a REF property but no such column exists in your sample output. I looks like you are adding row values... not columns

Comment: Yes add a column before the products. Eventually get the  `T-89   T-75   T-22` too, because in my current output file there is only the `Y-23  Y-7  Y-71  `

Comment: Can you read the rest of my comment as weigh in on that as well? I made edits asking for more information

Comment: I would like to have a column or a cell with `ref:` inside to begin and get all products in my output I'll edit my question to show you the input file. I also know there is nothing in the `-value " "`because I will just put `ref:`again to make a column.

Comment: What you are asking for is more than just creating values. We need to merge rows together. Does your real data just have the 3 lines or are there many more than that? Depending it would be easier to treat this as a text file.

Comment: In my context, I have 300 lines, 8 columns (10 if we count the references). This is an Excel table .csv.

Comment: So lines are "paired" then? Every line has its partner right below it that is to be merged (except the header of course)?

Comment: Oh sorry I did something wrong in my question wait a sec. So, as you can see there is only the Y products in my current output file. The input has been edited. I don't show my datas because it would be too long.

Comment: Ok. That is simpler then. Thanks for the edit. It was getting weird there for a minute.

Comment: I didn't dreak my coffee today, that's all ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be simpler if we just treat the file as a flat text file and save it in a csv format. You *could* use the csv objects and shift the values into other rows but that is not really necessary. Your approach of adding columns via `Add-Member` is not accomplishing this goal as it will be *adding new* columns and would not match your desired output. `Export-CSV` wants to write to file objects with the same properties as well which you were mixing which gave your unexpected results.

This is a verbose way of doing this. You could shorten this easily with something like regular expressions (see below). I opted for this method since it is a little easier to follow what is going on.

```
# Equivelent to Get-Content $filepath. This just shows what I am doing and is a portable solution.
$fileContents = "A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H",
"T-89;T-75;T-22;Y-23;Y-7;Y-71",
"T-89;T-75;T-22;Y-23;Y-7;Y-71"

 $newFile = "C:\temp\csv.csv"

# Write the header to the output file.
$fileContents[0] | Set-Content $newFile 

# Process the rest of the lines. 
$fileContents | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{
    # Split the line into its elements
    $splitLine = $_ -split ";"

    # Rejoin the elements. adding the ref strings
    (@("ref:") + $splitLine[0..2] + "ref2:" + $splitLine[3..5]) -join ";"
} | Add-Content $newFile
```

What the last line is going is concatenating an array. Starts with "ref:" add the first 3 elements of the split line followed by "ref2:" and the remaining elements. That new array is joined on semicolons and sent down the pipe to be outputted to the file.

---

If you are willing to give regex  a shot this could be done with less code.

```
$fileContents = Get-Content "C:\source\file\path.csv"
$newFile = "C:\new\file\path.csv"
$fileContents[0] | Set-Content $newFile
($fileContents | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace "((?:.*?;){3})(.*)",'ref:;$1ref2:;$2' | Add-Content $newFile
```

What that does is split each line beyond the first on the 3rd semicolon ([Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/op3nLN/1)). The replacement string is built from the ref strings and the matched content.

Comment: So, it creates new elements and how do you display them before the products I don't understand the `(@("ref:") + $splitLine[0..2] + "ref2:" + $splitLine[3..5]) -join ";"`. Then don't need to export my input file ?

Comment: @TELhon I added more about that and another solution.

Comment: What should give the final code with your second option, I don't really see  where could you put this.

Comment: I don't understand the question? The only thing that is missing is the source and destination files. The code is complete otherwise.

Comment: Ok ok, I'll try to make it works with this one the other works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select-Object` to specify order.

Assuming your headers are `A`-`H` (I know that instead of `A` it should be `ref`, from the code, but not sure if `T-89` etc are your other headers)

```
$NewCSVObject | Select-Object A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H | Export-Csv -Path ".\test2.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: Nothing changed and yes they are my headers, the problem is I want to export the `$csv`and the `$NewCSVObject` but one of them is not exported after the run. Export my datas and the new column but is it just possible to create it without exporting ?